# React Hook List size - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i am currently working on hooks and i am trying to create a sentence when buttons are clicked, and validating them if they are correct. However, to do this, **my list has to be only 5 words max, and i am having trouble to do so.**

The idea is that, when the list arrives to 5 values it has its maximum size. And when another value is added, it pops out the first value (of index 0) and adds the last value.

here is my code:

```
  const [sentence, setSentence] = useState([]);

  if(sentence==='HelloYouAreMyFriend'){
    console.log('sentence')
  }

        </View>
  <View> 
  {selectedWord.word.map(word => (
    <TouchableOpacity key={word}
onPress={() => setCount(sentence + word )}

  }>

Example 
        // 1 button click: Hello
        // 2 button click: HelloYou
        // 3 button click: HelloYouAre
        // 4 button click: HelloYourAreMy
        // 5 button click: HelloYourAreMyFriend
        // 6 button click: YourAreMyFriendJosh 
        Need SIZE max ==> 5 words in the list
```

Comment: What is `count` variable intended for?

Comment: The **count** is a list that add words one after the other

Comment: Tip: Always use a meaningful name for the variables and functions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you that you are handling all stuff in `handlePlaySound` function.

```
const[sentence, setSentence] = useState([]);

const handlePlaySound = (event) => {
const word = event.target.key
const localSentence = [...sentence]; //because you never mutate the state
  if (localSentence.length < 5) {
    setSentence([...localSentence], word)
  } else { 
    localSentence.splice(0,1);
    setSentence([...localSentence], word);
  }
}
```

and from component you should pass word in an event

```
<TouchableOpacity key={word} onPress={handlePlaySound} />
```